# Thickness of the Boundary Layer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, boundary-layer

Given an ODE

$$\epsilon y''+2xy'=x \cos(x)$$

with boundary condition $y(\pm {\pi \over 2})=2$

Where is the boundary layer and what is the thickness of it?

Comment: What do you call boundary layer and its thickness? Could you define those terms?

Comment: @user37238 Boundary layer is a narrow region for which the solution of the differential equation change rapidly. Also, the thickness of a boundary layer should goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

### Outer solution

You have the outer equation
$$
y'=\tfrac12\cos x\implies y(x)=C+\tfrac12\sin x
$$
Provided there are no jumps (rapid changes) at the outer boundaries, the left boundary condition leads to $y(x)=\tfrac52+\tfrac12\sin x$, the right boundary condition to $y(x)=\tfrac32+\tfrac12\sin x$

---

### Where the inner or boundary layer is not

For the inner parametrization $x=x_0+δ X$ and $Y(X)=y(x_0+δ X)$ the equation reads
$$
ϵY''+2δ(x_0+δ X)Y'=δ^2(x_0+δ X)\cos(x_0+δ X).
$$
For $x_0\notin\{-\frac\pi2,0,\frac\pi2\}$ a first reduction of infinitesimal versus appreciable quantities leads to
$$
ϵY''+2δx_0Y'=δ^2x_0\cos(x_0)
$$
where the only interesting case is for $δ\sim ϵ$. Taking $ϵ=2δ·|x_0|$ leads to the observation that the solution to the inner equation $Y''\pm Y'=0$ must be locally constant, since the exponential term of it is unbounded. However, to be locally (nearly) constant is equivalent to being continuous, which is satisfied by the outer solutions.

---

For $x_0=\pm\frac\pi2$ the right side reduces to $\mp δ^3x_0^2$, the reduced equation thus corresponds to the former case. The exponential term of the solution is still not bounded inside the interval, thus providing no jump.

---

### Inner layer

For $x_0=0$, $x=δX$, a first reduction of the singular equation removing non-essential infinitesimals reads as
$$
ϵY''+2δ^2 XY'=δ^3 X.
$$
Since $δ^3\ll δ^2$ the only non-trival case appears for $ϵ=δ^2$. The reduced inner equation is
$$
Y''+2XY'=0\implies Y'=C·e^{-X^2}\implies Y(X)=C·\int_0^Xe^{-s^2}ds+D
$$
with limits $Y(-\infty)=D-C·\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$ and $Y(\infty)=D+C·\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$.

---

### Approximation formula

For the jump from $\frac52$ to $\frac32$ one needs $D=2$ and $C=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ giving the total approximation as
$$
y_{approx}(x)=2+\tfrac12\bigl(\sin x-\text{erf}(x/\sqrtϵ)\bigr)
$$

---

The exponent for the boundary layer thickness is thus $\frac12$.

[image]