# Boundary layer problem(s): locating boundary layer(s) & asymptotic matching.

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Trying to get my head around the generic method of handling boundary layer problems.  For example,

$$\epsilon y''(x) - x^2y'(x) -y = 0, \qquad y(0)=y(1)=1.$$

After following lecture notes and some of the examples on Stackexchange (e.g. [Boundary value problem with rescaling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533481/boundary-value-problem-with-rescaling/1534807) or [Thickness of the Boundary Layer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290782/thickness-of-the-boundary-layer)), I've a rough idea of what's going on and can do the scaling at the boundary layers using $x = x_0 + e^\alpha X$ type subtitutions but still not sure about some aspects.

In the above example, the notes I have show that there is a boundary layer at x=0 because the outer layer is singular at x=0 (which I understand).  It also says that there is a boundary layer at x=1 because $-x^2$ is monotonically decreasing on the interval $[0,1]$

i. Is there a general rule for identifying boundary layers such as at $x=1$ *a priori* (or for that matter from the outer layer)?

ii. Why does the coefficient of $y'$ being negative on the interval cause the boundary layer at $x=1$?

iii. Will the boundary layer(s) always be at the end points or, in general, could there be a boundary layer in the middle of the interval (assuming 2nd order linear ODE).

For doing the asymptotic matching, I'd got that $y_{out}(x) = c_1 e^{1/x}$, $Y_{inner,right}(X) = c_3 + c_4 e^X$, and $Y_{inner,left}(X) = c_5 e^X + c_6 e^{-X}$.

iv. What's the proper way of doing the asymptotic matching?  I'd managed to handle the right side with the outer layer (assuming $X \to -\infty$)but the left side with the outer layer seems to require ignoring the limit going to infinity on both sides of the equation.

Comment: This discussion in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546644/131807) might help.

Comment: at $x=1$, $y\sim y'x^2$ are of the same order which signals that something is going on at this point

Answer (score 1):

Balancing at $x=0$ has the interesting case that the second coefficient has a root there. Let's start with the inner solutions, set $x=\delta X$ and $Y(X)=y(x)=y(δX)$. Then
$$
Y'(X)=δy'(δX)
\\~\\
ϵY''(X)=ϵδ^2y''(δX)=δ^2(x^2y'(x)+y(x))=δ^3X^2Y'(X)+δ^2Y(X)
$$
This suggests $ϵ=δ^2$, with $Y(X)=Ce^{-X}$ as the solution bounded in $[0,\infty)$, $C=1$ with the initial condition.

At $x=1$ the coefficients have not peculiarity, so set $x=1+δX$, $Y(X)=y(x)$ to get
$$
ϵY''(X)=δ^2(x^2y'(x)+y(x))=δY'(X)+δ^2Y(X)+O(δ^2),
$$
so that the balance is for $ϵ=δ$ giving $Y(X)=C+De^{X}$ which is bounded on $(-\infty,0]$, as required for a boundary layer, $C+D=1$ for the boundary condition.

The outer solution is $y(x)=ce^{1/x}$, which is not bounded and has no limit for $x\to 0$ for non-zero $c$. This forces $c=0$, so that the combination of inner and outer solutions gives
$$
y_{\rm approx}(x)=e^{-x/\sqrtϵ}+e^{-(1-x)/ϵ}.
$$